# Nginx and php-fpm trouble again

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Dears

I try to deploy wordpress on amazon ec2, I am facing the trouble on nginx and php-fpm, thanks for your help in advance.
I got the error as the following when nginx and php-fpm are running.

```
[error] 16282#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,
```

But if I stop php-fpm, and use "php-cgi -b 9000" instead, it works fine. 
I have another question is how to debug the issue on nginx and php-fpm, it throws little error message in the log files even I set log level to debug or info. 
Looking forward to get your response. Thanks a lot.

The following is my configue files.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;
    root /usr/www/ROOT/wordpress;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;


    #location ~ \.(htm|html|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|ico|css|js|txt)$ {
    #    root /usr/www/ROOT/wordpress;
    #    expires 24h;
    #}

    location / {
    #    root   /usr/www/ROOT/wordpress;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    #    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    #location / {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}


    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        #root   /usr/www/ROOT/wordpress;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/www/ROOT/wordpress$fastcgi_script_name;
    #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

part of the config in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
[www]

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses on a
;                            specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

; Set listen(2) backlog. A value of '-1' means unlimited.
; Default Value: -1
;listen.backlog = -1

; List of ipv4 addresses of FastCGI clients which are allowed to connect.
; Equivalent to the FCGI_WEB_SERVER_ADDRS environment variable in the original
; PHP FCGI (5.2.2+). Makes sense only with a tcp listening socket. Each address
; must be separated by a comma. If this value is left blank, connections will be
; accepted from any ip address.
; Default Value: any
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions. 
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0660
;listen.owner = nobody
;listen.group = nobody
;listen.mode = 0660

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
; RPM: apache Choosed to be able to access some dir as httpd
user = apache
; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
group = apache
```

Comment: I have a feeling that you have SCRIPT_FILENAME declared in fastcgi_params file as well and it doesn't point to the right location. Or `apache` user does not have permissions to access those files. Try using runusuer and run `php-cgi -b 9000` as `apache`.

Comment: Are the parent directories of your directory readable and traversable?

Comment: Thank a lot for your response, very kind of you. I tried to run php-cgi as apache, it works again. And it did not declare SCRIPT_FILENAME in fastcgi_params file, the file is the default one.

Comment: To Michael: Thanks. I have rudely run "chmod 777 -R" to the root of wordpress directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the extra `fastcgi_param` lines before including `fastcgi_params` file. This means that `fastcgi_params` defines will override the ones you define here.

So, move `include fastcgi_params` before `fastcgi_param` lines.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your way, but it did not work. It works if I use "php-cgi -b 9000".... So I guess the issue is on php-fpm side.